# I need som help with price ratios.

Tags: economics

Okay, so I'm doing some econ. homework and I'm supposed to draw a graph where the
relative price of $P$ is $4 T/P$. Thing is that my brain stops working anytime I try to think about ratios.

I know that it's supposed to be a line connecting some point on the $T$ axis to another point on the $P$ axis, and one is supposed to be $4$ times bigger than the other, but I just can't figure out which.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a horizontal $P$ axis and a vertical price axis.  $T$ is some parameter that you should be given, or you can make the units on the vertical axis be scaled by $T$.  You then compute a bunch of points (P, price), where price=$4T/P$ and plot them